# Searching a value in excel using formula

Tags: excel, for-loop, excel-formula

I want to search in excel in such a way, that if the pair is the same as another pair then print true else print false.

for example in below image, in row A1, one pair is {16-10-2020, Ayush} and other pair in column {b5,b6} is missing so, in b4 column, A1 row value is false.

example 2: in A2 row, one pair is {20-10-2020,rocky} and other pair in column {b5,b6} is present in A6 row, thus, in A2 row at B4 column, condition is true.

**Can you suggest any formula or any shortcut for that. As I have a very large data set and manually it is not possible.**

[image: example pic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is in `A1:F8`, try:

```
=COUNTIFS(E$3:E$8,B3,F$3:F$8,C3)>0
```

---

[image]

Where `ONWAAR` is Dutch for `FALSE` and `WAAR` the equivalent to `TRUE`

Comment: I think OP means that both cells (date and name) should be in the same row too. That's why he says *pair*.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, I believe this does return the wanted results.

Comment: Omg, I'm so dumb, of course this works perfectly, I don't know why i got confused about the *pair* thing, but indeed this is exactly what OP needs.